# Getting certain JS code to wait until another command finishes for it to execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using `AJAX` within `jQuery` and have the below code:

```
getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'GET', 'json')

    .done(function(response) {

        if (response.result == 'success') {

            $('#edit-form-holder').html(response.output);

            $('.listing .members-head .extra-cols').hide();

            $("#edit-member").css('display', 'block').animate({opacity: 1.0, left: edit_user_offset}, 1800);            

            $('.listing .members-data .extra-cols').hide();

        } else {

            //........

        }

    })

    .fail(function() {
        //........
    })

// End
```

`getAjaxData` is just a reference to my custom function that is not relevant for this issue.

The issue is..

I want this code...

```
$('.listing .members-data .extra-cols').hide();
```

To wait until the code below has finished executing..

```
$("#edit-member").css('display', 'block').animate({opacity: 1.0, left: edit_user_offset}, 1800);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the complete callback of `animate` method

```
$("#edit-member").css('display', 'block').animate({
    opacity: '1',
    left: edit_user_offset
}, 1800, function() {
    $('.listing .members-data .extra-cols').hide();
});
```

Also, the `opacity` value should be put in quotes if you want to use it as `1.0`. There is no need to add `.0` to opacity. You can also use this value as Number if you want to use `1` as value.

You can use `show` instead of `css(...` to show an element.

You can read more about `animate` from jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/